# Table with dynamic number of columns in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, multiple-columns

I want to create a table with dynamic number of columns in android I know how to add rows dynamically using LayoutInflator but how to add columns dynamically?

Thank you for your time any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont add columns - only rows and after that you can tell every view how many columns need to span

```
android:layout_span 

Defines how many columns this child should span. Must be >= 1. 

Must be an integer value, such as "100". 

This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type. 

This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol layout_span.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_span

one of the best Tuts: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_table-layout/

Comment: Thanks the link for the tutorial was good I solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use Listview and create a custom layout for row.Use a linear layout with orientation horizontal for row

```
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:weightSum="100" // or some other values
```

inside this linear layout you can add any number of columns.You can control the width by setting layout weight,You can do this in java dynamically.And make the width of each cell zero and height match_parent.So that your text will be correctly wrapped in each cell.

Setting weight is better than setting width directly since it uses free space and your table will be correctly displayed inside the screen

//Edit

Add a linearlayout in your layout

```
<LinearLayout 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >
```

Next we have to create columns.Actually it should be like this, here you get 2 columns with half size

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
     />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
     />
```

If you want to do this dynamically you have to write code to create Textview or any other view in java src and set its layout weight as 100/no of columns. 
You can set weight in layout parameters.

Comment: can you elaborate or give some link please

Comment: Thank you now I understand.....but I am facing a new problem I have created the table but now I want to retrieve data from it when user clicks ok. The problem is I have used a seperate layout for a single row and inflated a table layout with it to get the table but there is a spinner in each row which user can change so how to get the value of each spinner because each spinner does not have a unique id

Comment: Write the listener of spinner in getview.And a separate variable to store its position.Initialize this variable when setting listener.